# fatal error: linux/gpio/machine.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to write descriptor-based GPIO interface in x86 from linux driver development book by john madieu i came to know

> With the descriptor-based interface, prior to allocating and taking the ownership of GPIOs, those GPIOs must have been mapped somewhere. By mapped, I mean they should be assigned to your device, whereas, with the legacy integer-based interface, you just have to fetch a number anywhere and request it as a GPIO. Actually, there are three kinds of mapping in the kernel.

I decided to choose "Platform data mapping" method to mapping to kernel, for that I have gone through the document https://djwong.org/docs/kdoc/driver-api/gpio/board.html.

It mentions `gpiod_lookup_table` and `gpios_table()` can be used to update lookup table. For using this function I use

```
#include <linux/gpio/machine.h>
```

in my code. But when compile it, I got an error:

```
fatal error: linux/gpio/machine.h: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please help to figure it out?

I'm using kernel version 3.10.

Comment: Update your kernel from ancient to something reasonable. And your choice is bad. Don't do platform data mapping in new code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install linux-headers-3.10.* package in your development machine (depending on your exact kernel version).

Comment: Thank for reply.. i have my linux_3_10 in git repository so i can add or install header package can you please guide me

Comment: If you are using a debian based distribution, you can run
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-cache search linux-headers-3.10*;
Get the exact package name and run the command: 
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-XX